# How do I get access to the chrome.sidePanel API from the latest manifest v3?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to automatically open the side panel by clicking the chrome extension icon. Having read the documentation on the different APIs, it seems that this should be possible using the chrome.sidePanel API.

But, I am struggling to access the API in vscode (I am writing in typescript)
My current manifest.json file includes:

```
"manifest_version": 3

"minimum_chrome_version": "114.0.5735.134"

"side_panel": {
  "default_path": "sidepanel.html",
  "openPanelOnActionClick": true
  }

"permissions": "sidePanel"
```

My current package.json file includes:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.237",
```

What could be the reason that I am not able to access/use the sidePanel API?

I have tried to refresh both vscode and my computer.

Comment: 1) It should be an array `"permissions": ["sidePanel"]` 2) openPanelOnActionClick should be used in the service worker (background script) as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/#open-action-icon).

Comment: 1) Sorry, my bad, I already have it as an array. For the purpose of the question I removed the other permissions
2) I agree, and that is my goal. However, I believe in order to do that I have to use the "chrome.sidePanel"-API first...

Comment: Use the example I linked which is showing how to set openPanelOnActionClick in the service worker. You'll need to declare a service worker as shown in the [respective documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/basics/). You can call the API inside chrome.runtime.onInstalled event.

Comment: I works when I am using JavaScript, but it does not work when I use typescript...

Comment: It means there's a problem in your code or in your ts config.

Answer (score 2):

In order to open the sidepanel upon clicking the extension icon ('action' i guess) then you can add this code in the background file:

```
// Allows users to open the side panel by clicking on the action toolbar icon
chrome.sidePanel
  .setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

You can also do the same with the context menu:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'openSidePanel') {
    // This will open the panel in all the pages on the current window.
    //TODO: Figure out this typescript error
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ windowId: tab?.windowId });
  }
});
```

Permissions:
`permissions: ['sidePanel', 'storage', 'contextMenus', 'activeTab', 'tabs'],`

Not sure what you mean by "access it in vs code", bc once you've loaded the ext into chrome, you are accessing it from there (hopefully the background script)